# How to redirect a URL using the .htaccess-file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, directory, root

My website has a library / directory path like:

{root}/pages/{files}.php

My index.php path is the following: {root}/index.php

I want, that when people go to (as an example) 'login.php' (which exists in the /pages directory. that the url does not contains the '/pages'.

So:

www.website.com/pages/dashboard.php

Redirects to

wwww.website.com/dashboard.php

And that it is possible that when people access www.website.com/dashboard.php they can access this page.

Sorry for the bad explaining, can't find the good words for it.

**Edit : This is my .htacces now**

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite automatic to /index.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$

# Second check for if above doesn't do the job [www/https].
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index [R=301,L]

# Delete all the .php and .html extensions from files [url-related].
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

# Prevent people for looking inside the .htacces file.
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

And I did try this:
RewriteRule ^/?pages/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

(Which did redirect me, but still received a 404 error.

Comment: Well, there are literally millions of examples for simple redirection rules alone here on SO. So the question is: what is it you need as additional info? Why don't all those answers not answer _your_ question?

Comment: I've literally zero knowledge of .htacces. So I can try all this answers, which I obviously did. But in all cases I ended up with or:

1. I couldn't browse my file direct (so it did redirect when I tried via /pages/file.php but did not work when acces the link just domain/file.php

2. Or it worked but redirected to .php (with extension) which I've turned off.

For me .htacces is like Chinese.

Comment: So please add that attempt you made, along with a precise description of the issues, so that we can help with that.

Comment: Did add some more information to the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do that with .htaccess only. (EDIT: you can, see "EDIT" below)

What you want is to PRETEND that login.php were in the root directory, but actually it is not.

**EDIT:** I think I mixed it up. You could do it with the .htaccess-file only. But I don't recommend it. You would have to add all redirections per hand (or develop expressions for the different cases).
Instead, I propose to use the following technique. It is basically the start of a self-made Content-Management-System, where the user can create pages on their own and name the URL leading to this page. Also, this all can be extended to an ajax-supporting website to be really up-to-date!

### Using .htaccess only

In case you are not interested in the named advantages of the controller-technique, replace the code in your .htaccess-file and your login-page-problem is solved.

```
RewriteEngine on
#catch www.example.com/login.php and redirect without user's conciousness to www.example.com/pages/login.php
RewriteRule ^(login.php)$ http://www.example.com/pages/login.php [NC,L,QSA]
# Prevent people from looking inside the .htacces file.
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

In case you want to gain more (and actually helpful) knowledge and want to learn a universal technique of how to start a CMS with the named advantages, continue reading!

### Goal of this example

When the user calls the URL "www.example.com/login", the login-page ("login.php") will be loaded.

### Setup

You need a .htaccess-file in the root directory.
You need a "controller" in the root directory (I propose index.php).
You need content pages somewhere, in this example a file called "login.php" in root/pages.
Htaccess will redirect all URLs to this controller, also it passes the URL originally called by the user. Based on the passed URL the controller decides which page content to load. In our case it will be login.php.

### Controller

path: root/index.php

```
<?php

    function callPage($data) {
        if (isset($data['path'])) {
            // get the correct file for the given path
              switch ($data['path']) {
                  case "login":
                      include("/pages/login.php");
                      break;
                  default:
                      // show 404 error if given path is unknown
                      include("/pages/error.php");
              }
        }
    }

?>

<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="page"><?php callPage($_GET); ?><!-- load called page's content --></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Example content page

path: root/pages/login.php

```
<p>I am a happy login page. See, that I don't need any HTML Tags, a body or a head, because I am meant to be used only when mother index.php calls me up and integrates me. Life's so easy!</p>
<p>And do you know what's the best? I can even run PHP inside myself! Awesome, isn't it?</p>
```

### .htaccess-file

path: root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
#if called file or directory reallyexists, don't redirect (might lead into a loop)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#redirect every URL (that does not really exist) to index.php
#the URL the user called can be accessed in index.php in $_GET['path']
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exampe.com/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# Prevent people from looking inside the .htacces file.
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

### Impulses

This is of course a very basic example. Currently, there is no advantage in using this technique instead of a simple redirection in the .htaccess-file, rather only disadvantages. But it is now on your own to enhance it. Some possibilities:

index.php: Replace the switch with a database call. It takes the user's url and returns the corresponding "real" URL (the one the user never sees)

Add a title to the page (also saved in database)

Implement an Ajax-support for your website

In the end, this leads to a small system, which can be extended to an own CMS

Comment: Ah, get it. Is there a possibility you can help me with it?

Comment: Sure, currently working on it ;) Luckily for you I did exactly this just 4 days ago

Comment: Ah, thanks! Love the way people here like helping new people into the Community.

Comment: No welcome, in the end the one hand washs the other ;)